# R tm package select huge amount of words to keep in text corpus

Tags: r, tm

I have around 70.000 `frequent_words` which I want to keep in a text corpus in the same order they appeared (order matters). Which i got like this:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(txt_corpus, control = list(wordLengths=c(1, Inf)))
frequent_words <- findFreqTerms(dtm, lowfreq=50)
```

Just doing:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(txt_corpus, control = list(wordLengths=c(1, Inf)))
dtm <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.8)
```

Would not work since I need that same filtered `text_corpus` twice:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(txt_corpus, control = list(wordLengths=c(1, Inf)))
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) unlist(lapply(ngrams(words(x), 2), paste, collapse = " "), use.names = FALSE)
bidtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(txt_corpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
```

I tried the code below:

```
keepWords <- content_transformer(function(x, words) {
  regmatches(x,
             gregexpr(paste0("(\\b",  paste(words, collapse = "\\b|\\b"), "\\b)"), x, perl = T, ignore.case=T, useBytes = T)
             , invert = T) <- " "
  return(x)
})
txt_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, keepWords, frequent_words)
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
Error in gregexpr(paste0("(\\b", paste(words, collapse = "\\b|\\b"), "\\b)"),  : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634
Calls: preprocess ... tm_parLapply -> lapply -> FUN -> FUN -> regmatches<- -> gregexpr
Execution halted
```

This is caused due to the long regular expression. Removing non frequent words is out of the question since `length(less_frequent_words)` > 1.000.000 and takes to long with:

```
chunk <- 500
n <- length(less_frequent_words)
r <- rep(1:ceiling(n/chunk),each=chunk)[1:n]
d <- split(less_frequent_words, r)

for (i in 1:length(d)) {
  txt_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, removeWords, c(paste(d[[i]])))
}
```

I also tried something with joining but it gives me a unique text corpus in each iteration:

```
chunk <- 500
n <- length(frequent_words)
r <- rep(1:ceiling(n/chunk),each=chunk)[1:n]
d <- split(frequent_words, r)

joined_txt_corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(list()))
for (i in 1:length(d)) {
  new_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, keepWords, c(paste(d[[i]])))
  joined_txt_corpus <- c(joined_txt_corpus, new_corpus)
  txt_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, removeWords, c(paste(d[[i]])))
}
txt_corpus <- joined_txt_corpus
```

Is there an efficient way to do the same selection like `text_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, keepWords, frequent_words)` but with many words? Any help and hints are appreciated! Thanks!

Reproducable example:

```
library(tm)
data(crude)

txt_corpus <- crude

txt_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
txt_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, removePunctuation)
txt_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, stripWhitespace)

article_words <- c("a", "an", "the")
txt_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, removeWords, article_words)
txt_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, removeNumbers)

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(txt_corpus, control = list(wordLengths=c(1, Inf)))
frequent_words <- findFreqTerms(dtm, lowfreq=80)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(txt_corpus, control = list(wordLengths=c(1, Inf), dictionary=frequent_words))

# Use many words just using frequent_words once works
# frequent_words <- c(frequent_words, frequent_words, frequent_words, frequent_words)

# keepWords function
keepWords <- content_transformer(function(x, words) {
  regmatches(x,
             gregexpr(paste0("(\\b",  paste(words, collapse = "\\b|\\b"), "\\b)"), x, perl = T, ignore.case=T)
             , invert = T) <- " "
  return(x)
})

txt_corpus <- tm_map(txt_corpus, keepWords, frequent_words)

# Get bigram from text_corpus
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) unlist(lapply(ngrams(words(x), 2), paste, collapse = " "), use.names = FALSE)
bidtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(txt_corpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
bidtmm <- col_sums(bidtm)
bidtmm <- as.matrix(bidtmm)
print(bidtmm)
```

Output:

```
        [,1]
in in     14
in of     21
in oil    19
in to     28
of in     21
of of     20
of oil    20
of to     29
oil in    18
oil of    18
oil oil   13
oil to    33
to in     32
to of     35
to oil    21
to to     41
```

Comment: A reproducible example would be nice. You could use the crude dataset in tm as a starting point. Not having seen the expected output, why don't you use a dictionairy?

Comment: Thanks I updated the question with an example. What do you mean by dictionary?

Comment: What is your exact wanted output based on crude[[1]] using a lowfreq of 10 or 20? Normally I would say a dictionary, like `DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control = list(dictionary = frequent_words))`, but that just counts the words in the frequent_words and gets rid of the rest.

Comment: Yes it works but I also want in the bidtm count the words which appear together with only the frequent words. I updated the example see the `bidtmm` matrix which I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your requirements and maybe a combination to tm and quanteda can help. See below.

Once you have a list of frequent words you can use quanteda in parallel to get the bigrams.

```
library(quanteda)

# set number of threads 
quanteda_options(threads = 4) 

my_corp <- corpus(crude) # corpus from tm can be used here (txt_corpus)
my_toks <- tokens(my_corp, remove_punct = TRUE) # add extra removal if needed

# Use list of frequent words from tm. 
# speed gain should occur here
my_toks <- tokens_keep(my_toks, frequent_words)

# ngrams, concatenator is _ by default
bitoks <- tokens_ngrams(my_toks)

textstat_frequency(dfm(bitoks)) # ordered from high to low

   feature frequency rank docfreq group
1    to_to        41    1      12   all
2    to_of        35    2      15   all
3   oil_to        33    3      17   all
4    to_in        32    4      12   all
5    of_to        29    5      14   all
6    in_to        28    6      11   all
7    in_of        21    7       8   all
8   to_oil        21    7      13   all
9    of_in        21    7      10   all
10  of_oil        20   10      14   all
11   of_of        20   10       8   all
12  in_oil        19   12      10   all
13  oil_in        18   13      11   all
14  oil_of        18   13      11   all
15   in_in        14   15       9   all
16 oil_oil        13   16      10   all
```

quanteda does have a `topfeatures` function, but it doesn't work like `findfreqterms`. Otherwise you could do it completely in quanteda.

If the `dfm` generation is taking too much memory, you can use as.character to transform the token object and use this either in dplyr or data.table. See code below.

```
library(dplyr)
out_dp <- tibble(features = as.character(bitoks)) %>% 
  group_by(features) %>% 
  tally()


library(data.table)
out_dt <- data.table(features = as.character(bitoks))
out_dt <- out_dt[, .N, by = features]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to avoid `dfm(bitoks)` since it generates a huge matrix which does not fit in memory for me (32Gb) since it is very sparse. I get the error:

Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c, line 147
Calls: preprocess_opt ... dfm -> dfm.tokens -> sparseMatrix -> as -> asMethod
Execution halted
Warning message:
system call failed: Cannot allocate memory

Comment: Some kind of splitting into chunks and then later join them and use textstat_frequency maybe?

Comment: I added some dplyr and data.table code. If you have a lot of features, data.table will be faster.

Comment: You are amazing!